# converting image to data frame with columns for coordinates and pixel value in R

Tags: r, spatstat

I want to convert a remote sensing image into `data.frame` with two column for xy coordinates and third column for the pixel value. This is the default data input for
`ppmlasso`.

The original image is imported in R as matrix with no prior coordinates. min and max coordinates and resolution are given in a text file so I use them to create an `im` class for `spatstat`. 
Here is a simple example with lets say `seq` of decimal coordinates e.g. the image has 10 m resolution.

```
mat <- matrix(seq(1,20, by=1), nrow=4, ncol=5)  
m <- mat[4:1,]
i <- im(m, xcol = seq(5,45, by=10), yrow = seq(5,35,by=10)) 
plot(i, axes = T)
print(mat)
```

So far two different representation of RS data - `matrix` and `im`. Now i want a third representation - a `data.frame` with two columns for coordinates pairs and a third column for the respective RS value. Intuitively I did this:

```
r <- raster(i)
v <- as.vector(as.matrix(r))
df <- cbind(coordinates(r),v)
print(df)
```

The reason to go to `raster` is to use `coordinates` call. The result however is wrong - coordinates pairs and values from matrix don't match, because `coordinates` are called in order starting from top row going along the entire row,while `as.vector` calls values by column.

Suggestions?

Comment: `transform(arrayInd(mat, .dim = dim(mat), useNames = T), val = as.vector(mat))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
as.data.frame(i)
#    x  y value
#1   5  5     4
#2   5 15     3
#3   5 25     2
#4   5 35     1
#5  15  5     8
#6  15 15     7
#7  15 25     6
#8  15 35     5
#9  25  5    12
#10 25 15    11
#11 25 25    10
#12 25 35     9
#13 35  5    16
#14 35 15    15
#15 35 25    14
#16 35 35    13
#17 45  5    20
#18 45 15    19
#19 45 25    18
#20 45 35    17
```

should do it ;)

Comment: Thanks. that was easy. Additional question. Suppose we have list of several im with same extend, and desire data.frame with xy coords and all the values. is this the cleanest way: `list.df <- lapply(list.im, function(x) {as.data.frame(x)})` ; as you said. Then combine all into one df. `df <- as.data.frame(list.df)` ; and subset only fist xy and all the values, getting rid of redundant xy `df <- df[, c(1:2, seq(3,228, by = 3))]`

Comment: for most types of analyses you will probably be better off if you arrange your data into a long data.frame with columns <image_id>, x, y, value -- see vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html:  each variable is a column, each observation is a row.